# Binary String Question to find maximum power of 2

Tags: c++, string, math, bit

We have given a binary String of length n,we  can cyclically shift this string any number of times.Let X  be the decimal representation of string s. Find the greatest power of  2 with which X can be divisible with, if it can be divisible with arbitrarily large power print "-1".For the result, you are required to print a single integer denoting the maximum power of 2  by which X  can be divisible with.
ex:
Input:
0011
Output:
2

Explanation:We can cyclically shift the string 2 times to get "1100" which is divisible by 2^2 hence the answer is 2.

Here is my solution .. however it is giving me tle on most of the test cases and wrong answer on some of the test cases..

```
int highestpower(int n)
{
    return (n & (~(n - 1)));
}

int findnum(string s)
{
    int value = 0;
    int p=0;
    for(int i = s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        value = value+pow(2,p)*(s[i]-'0');
        p++;
    }
    return value;
}

int maximumPower(string s) {
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        
        int num = findnum(s.substr(i)+s.substr(0,i));
        ans = max(ans,highestpower(num));
    }
    return ans/2;
}
```

how can I solve this answer?Thanks..

Comment: Why not simply trying to find the maximum length subarray of consecutive zeros, in a cyclic way?

Comment: Can u please explain ur appraoch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some difficulty to understand the logic of your code. In practice, it failed on about all cases I have tested.

Moreover, it seems quite over-complicated. It is enough to count the number of consecutive zeros. We just have to pay attention that
this calculation must be performed in a cyclic way. For example, if `s == 00100`, the count number is 4, as after shifting, we get `10000`. One simple way to handle this cyclicity is to concatenate the string `s2 = s+s = 0010000100` and then to count the maximum number of consecutive zeros in the obtained string `s2`. In addition, we must pay attention that the input string is not composed of zeros only.

In the following code, I compared your code (`maximumPower`) with mine (`maximumPower_new`), on several different inputs.

Result:

```
0011    : 2  new: 2
0100010 : 4  new: 3
00100   : 8  new: 4
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

int highestpower(int n)
{
    return (n & (~(n - 1)));
}

int findnum(const std::string& s)
{
    int value = 0;
    int p=0;
    for(int i = s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        value = value+pow(2,p)*(s[i]-'0');
        p++;
    }
    return value;
}

int maximumPower(const std::string& s) {
    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        int num = findnum(s.substr(i)+s.substr(0,i));
        ans = std::max(ans,highestpower(num));
    }
    return ans/2;
}

int maximumPower_new (const std::string& s) {
    int n = s.length();
    if (n == 0) return -1;
    std::string s2 = s + s;
    int count = 0;
    int count_max = 0;
    for (auto c: s2) {
        if (c == '0') {
            count ++;
        } else {
            count_max = std::max(count, count_max);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    count_max = std::max(count, count_max);
    if (count_max >= n) return -1;
    else return count_max;
}

int main() {
    for (std::string s: {"0011", "0100010", "00100"}) {
        std::cout << s << " : " << maximumPower(s) << " new: " << maximumPower_new(s) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain why we are finding maximum length subarray of consecutive zeros?In my appraoch I just rotate the string ,calculate the decimal value and just find max power of 2 .

Comment: I just count the 0 (`count ++`), until I get a 1. If it is the case (!= 0), then I reset the count. I memorize in count_max the maximum count obtained so far.

Comment: Yup I understood how u find the maximum zeros but why are we finding maximum zeros ,is there any relation between finding maximum zeros and maximum power of 2 that can divide the number?

Comment: If you find m consecutive zeros, then you can divide by 2^m, after a particular rotation. The little difficulty is to manage the fact that we can have some zeros at both start and end of the string. The advantage of using string and characters only, no int, is that we avoid potential overflow problems. Moreover, we don't have to perform rotations in practice.